# Magento Banner replacement with slideshow left to right

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento. I wanted to learn some stuff, however i am doing websites with php hand code from few years.

I have a website with third party template already working. What i wanted to do replace main Banner slide show (1 to 3 images rotating one by one) with featured slideshow showing/scrolling products from left to right(4 at a time) and each product should be clickable and would be linkable to database with featured listings etc.

Any ideas, basic tutorials, plugins?

Comment: You will need to specify which module you are using for slideshow and a link to the module if it's open source, only then someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins :-

1. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all-category-product-carousel.html

   2. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/featured-product-horizontal-carousel.html

Or you can use any carousel slide and replace with products in your collection